# Angular 2 - How to display spinner when waiting for observable and queryParams while navigating to another component?

Tags: angular

There are 2 components `Checkout` and `OrderSummary`.
In `Checkout` Component there is a button which on clicked will use a service  `createOrder()`.Once the `createOrder()` service is completed, it will navigate to `OrderSummary` Component  and send a `Order` Object as  `queryParams`  to  `OrderSummary` Component.How can a `spinner`or `loading` page be displayed between the navigation of 2 components.

Service in `Checkout` Component -

```
  onSubmit(){
    this.checkoutService.checkout(this.shippingMethod,this.shippingAddress,this.payment,this.billingAddress).subscribe(
      res=>{
          this.order = res.json();
          this.router.navigate(['/orderResult'],{queryParams:{order:JSON.stringify(this.order)}});
      },
      error=>{
          this.order.orderStatus = "failed";
          this.router.navigate(['/orderResult'],{queryParams:{order:JSON.stringify(this.order)}});
      }
    );

  }
```

In `OrderSummary` Component -

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(
      queryParams =>{
        this.order = JSON.parse(queryParams['order']);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.order));
        console.log(this.order.orderStatus);
        if(this.order.orderStatus == "placed"){
          this.orderResult = true;
        }
        this.cartItemList = this.order.cartItemList;
        this.estimatedDeliveryDate = this.order.shippingDate;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Create a function in a service to toggle the spinner/loader so that every component can use it. Then go in the required component's ngOnDestroy() and enable the spinner and disable it in another component's ngOnInit()

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan do i need to create a new component for that?,can spinner be displayed over `checkout` or `ordersummary` component? Please so a demo code of how this can be achieved.

Comment: That depends on how u want to show the spinner. You can just append a div from a function to the calling element or maybe you can append it to the body itself like from app.component but in that case the spinner will come in the entire screen

Comment: What I mean is <div id="spinner"></div> in app.component.html and it will be hidden by default and is only toggle to show/hide depending on the service function

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan i want to display the spinner over the `checkout` component but  not sure how to do it.Is there any reference you can provide?

Comment: Add <div class="spinner"></div> in checkout component html and show hide it using a variable whose value is changed by other component via service. The `spinner` class should have css of spinner/loader

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan this will hide the `Checkout` component previous data,i want to display a overlay ,rather than adding it on the same component.

Comment: No no it will not hide any data. Its will be a css and only this div will show hide rest other all elements will be visible. Now how u want to show it is all into the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution is
this.router.navigate() returns promise , i.e when navigation is done promise will fullfilled.
so you can use it like:

```
onSubmit() {
 this.showLoader()// your way of showing loader
 //await call api 
 this.router.navigate(['path']).then(res => {
this.hideLoader()})
}
```